# How to set existing Yii2 asset path

Tags: php, yii2, xampp

I'm totally new to Yii and I have an existing project to display. I placed the files under: `htdocs/myproject`.

The pages can be accessed using url: `localhost/myproject/web`, but some of asset css/js won't load because

```
Yii::$app->getAssetManager()->getPublishedUrl($this->getPublicAssetsLocation());
```

resulting in: `myproject/web/assets/assets1` (relative path)

So the final path becomes: localhost/**myproject/web/myproject/web**/assets/assets1, and it's broken path because of the duplicated directory path.

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [];
    public $js = [];
    public $depends = [];
}
```

I tried changing the base path, but ended up with 404 instead. How can I correct the path?

Comment: This has nothing to do with XAMPP. I use XAMPP with Yii2 often and have never had this problem. Could you show your config/web.php? Especially the configuration of the urlManager => [Rules []] component.

Comment: where and how are you using the output of the line you mentioned `Yii::$app->getAssetManager()->getPublishedUrl($this->getPublicAssetsLocation());`